# How can a diagram be created to allow collapsing and expanding of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, trees

I want to create an interactive diagram in LaTeX.

Right now I am using a Microsoft PowerPoint smart are tool, but it is missing functionality.

I want to create a hierarchy tree that displays up to set depth. The tree would have some method showing other sets of nodes.

I am very new to LaTeX but I did not see anything about possible libraries, or a reason as to why it does not work.

I thought of making the diagram up to a certain level, and then create a link of the slide with the next part of the diagram.

I am looking for a general strategy, e.g. what libraries would offer this behavior.

I am planing on writing some software to generate the LaTeX code, so even if the method is tedious that is okay.

**EDIT**:

I currently have a hierarchy of a system and its components.

e.g.

```
Device Foo
- Object 1
  - SubObject 1-1
- Object 2
- Object 3
  - SubObject 3-1
  - SubObject 3-2
.
.
.
- Object  n
  - Object n-m
  - ...
```

My dream goal would be to have something like one of these:

- [Treemap](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap)
- [Zoomable Circle Packing](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535)

Comment: Welcome! What doesn't work? What do you have so far? You talk about slides, but give no indication which class or whatever you're using for them. But probably, depending on all the details we don't have, you thought is the way to go.

Comment: I added detail and some examples of my "dream" goal.

Comment: Please provide the code you've got so far. Right now this is just a do-this-whole-complicated-thing-for-me-from-scratch. That's not how the site is supposed to work. You may get lucky, especially if you throw something cute in like a duck. Cats and witches are also popular. Trees are a bit seasonal, but you might have better luck in December. It is your project. Ask us for specific help with a step you can't do. You are more likely to get good help that way.

Comment: You say something doesn't work, but you don't know why. However, I have no idea *what* doesn't work or in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read a basic introduction to LaTeX? I ask, because your edit suggests that you are thinking of LaTeX in alien terms. (I suspect in terms which may be appropriate to other programming languages, but that's definitely not something I know anything about.) If you haven't, you should start by reading one so that you have a basic idea of how the system works. Otherwise, nothing is going to make much sense and no answer to your specific questions is going to mean much to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive PDF documents of such kind can be produced with TikZ and OCGs (aka PDF Layers).

The code below may serve as a starting point. It approximates Treemaps, as shown in the OP's first link.

It requires a recent version of the `ocgx2` package `[2017/03/07]`, available via `tlmgr` of TeX-Live, and Acrobat Reader in order to correctly control the visibility of the link areas placed on various layers of the document.

[image]

Open on [**ShareLaTeX:**](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58bfc68e7d3ad8290fe4106d)

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2]{standalone}

\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}[2017/03/07]

\begin{document}\Huge

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every scope/.style={ocg={opts={radiobtngrp=myTree}}},
    every node/.style={
      anchor=south west, thick, draw, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm},
    upnode/.code={\draw (0,5) node[show ocg=#1, anchor=north west, thin,
                    minimum width=0, minimum height=0] {\small up};}
]

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=Root, status=on}]
  \draw (0,0) node[show ocg=A] {A};
  \draw (5,0) node[show ocg=B] {B};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=A, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node[show ocg=A.1] {A.1};
  \draw (5,0) node[show ocg=A.2] {A.2};
  \tikzset{upnode=Root}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=A.1, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node[show ocg=A.1.1] {A.1.1};
  \draw (5,0) node {A.1.2};
  \tikzset{upnode=A}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=A.1.1, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node {A.1.1.1};
  \draw (5,2.5) node[minimum height=2.5cm] {A.1.1.2};
  \draw (5,0) node[minimum height=2.5cm] {A.1.1.3};
  \tikzset{upnode=A.1}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=A.2, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node {A.2.1};
  \draw (5,0) node {A.2.2};
  \tikzset{upnode=A}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=B, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node[show ocg=B.1] {B.1};
  \draw (5,0) node[show ocg=B.2] {B.2};
  \tikzset{upnode=Root}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=B.1, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node {B.1.1};
  \draw (5,0) node {B.1.2};
  \tikzset{upnode=B}
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[ocg={ref=B.2, status=off}]
  \draw (0,0) node {B.2.1};
  \draw (5,0) node {B.2.2};
  \tikzset{upnode=B}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```